# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin x}{\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How to evaluate

> $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin x}{\rm d}x~,~\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{\sin x}{\rm d}x$$

I have no idea.

Comment: Should it be $\sin(2nx)$ or $\sin(nx)$?

Comment: @Lovsovs it is $\sin(2nx)$

Comment: No idea but it seems to be a quite funny pattern.

Comment: A change of variables strongly suggests this converges to $\int_{\bf R_+} \sin(x){\rm d}x/x$. You can use integration by parts to bound the contribution of $x\geq 1/\sqrt{n}$ ; and use a Taylor expansion on ${\rm e}^{-x^2}/\sin(x)$ to estimate the integral when $0<x\leq 1/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)}$ as $$\frac{e^{2nix}-e^{-2nix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}= e^{(2n-1)ix}+\ldots+e^{-(2n-1)ix}$$
then compute
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\cos((2m+1)x)\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\text Re\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2-(2m+1)ix}\,dx$$
by completing the square and sum up everything.

Comment: It may be clear to others, but what is $m$?

Comment: @Lovsovs $m$ is a dummy variable summed over from $0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: @J.G. Great, thanks!

Comment: Two things 1) @Kamala I don't advise to end the computation by completing the square (you would have to check your path: in the complex plane !) ; I advise to compute the last integral as the Fourier Transform  of a gaussian i.e., a gaussian, computed at value $(2m+1)$. 2) The 2nd integral in the original question can be treated via Fejer's kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel

Comment: To SUMmarize, the final result of the first integral is $$\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{1}{4} (2 m+1)^2}$$.